# Navigate to another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a FragmentActivity which contains two fragments. For ex: fragment1 and fragment2.
Now fragment1 has two buttons.
I need to go to fragment3 on a button click in fragment1.

FragmentActivity has two buttons and a fragment place where I am replacing the two fragments on button clicks.
this is the layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".OnlineActionsActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onSelectFragment"
        android:text="fr1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onSelectFragment"
        android:text="fr2" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Now I am kind of lost how to achieve my goal !!
since fragment1 and fragment2 is a fragment not a fragmentactivity so I dont have getSupportFragmentManager().

And also how the layout of fragment1 will look like !! Would be great if anyone can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

The fragments have the method `getFragmentManager()` that you can use to make fragment transactions inside the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your fragment from fragment by writing few line of codes in Fragment1.

Layout of your Fragment1 will contain simple button and you should set an onclicklistener on this button and write this code in onClick() method.

```
final Activity a = getActivity();               
if (a instanceof YourFragmentActivity) {        
    final YourFragmentActivity activity = (YourFragmentActivity) a;               
    activity.updateContent(Fragment3.class.getSimpleName());
}
```

and This is updateContent method in FragmentActivity :

```
public void updateContent(String tag) {

        menulist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        Fragment fragment=null;


        final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        final FragmentTransaction tr = fm.beginTransaction();

        if (currentContentFragmentTag != null) {
          final Fragment currentFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(currentContentFragmentTag);
          if (currentFragment != null)
            tr.hide(currentFragment);
        }   

        if (tag.equals(Fragment1.class.getSimpleName())) {
            final Fragment foundFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(tag);
            if (foundFragment != null) {
                fragment = foundFragment;
            }
            else {
                fragment = new Fragment1();
            }
        } else if (tag.equals(Fragment2.class.getSimpleName())) {
            final Fragment foundFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(tag);
            if (foundFragment != null) {
                fragment = foundFragment;
            }
            else {
                fragment = new Fragment2();
            }
        } else if (tag.equals(Fragment3.class.getSimpleName())) {
            final Fragment foundFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(tag);
            if (foundFragment != null) {
                fragment = foundFragment;
            }
            else {
                fragment = new Fragment3();
            }
        } else {
            return;
        }

        if (fragment.isAdded()) {
            tr.show(fragment);
        }
        else {
            tr.add(R.id.fragment_place, fragment, tag);
        }

        tr.commit();

        currentContentFragmentTag = tag;
        ApiConstants.currentFragmentTag = tag;

    }
```